# releasing a new version of app that will update specific table in database-android

Tags: android, database

i have published a app on google play market. in which i have used SQLassethelper library for database connectivity.
actually my app is a tutorial app. in which there is also a table that stores favourite questions marked by user.
now i want to update the question table,
but my question is, if i release a new version of my app with updated question table, the favourite question's table will erase? right?
so how can i release a new version of my app, which will not erase the favourite table data of user, but will only update a particular table in that database?
is there any solution for my question?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Yes. It will be erased your data. You must perform operation in `onUpgrade()` method. In which you should implement `ALTER` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take care about your user data and there is  a `onUpgrade()` is there in `SQliteOpenHelper` class in which you can match your `database version` and if your database version is more then from your previous version then create new tables in `onUpgrade()` fucntion , And if you want to add new data to existing table then your need to write code to add new rows or update through `inert` or `update` query. 
Also you can Add new columns to existing tables through `alter` query.

please find more information about version upgarde .

https://riggaroo.co.za/android-sqlite-database-use-onupgrade-correctly/

And if you are added your database file in Asset for initial data  Then you need to change database `pragma` version thats is nothing but database version which we can pass in `SQliteOpenHelper` class.

see below sample of onUpgrade()

In our onUpgrade, we defined the following:

```
 @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Updating table from " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);

        //Added new column to book table - book rating 
        if (oldVersion < 2){
            db.execSQL(DROP + BookEntry.TABLE_NAME);
            db.execSQL(BookEntry.SQL_CREATE_BOOK_ENTRY_TABLE);
        }
        //Rename table to book_information - this is where things will start failing.
        if (oldVersion < 3){
            db.execSQL(DROP + BookEntry.TABLE_NAME);
            db.execSQL(BookEntry.SQL_CREATE_BOOK_ENTRY_TABLE);
        }
        // Add new column for a calculated value. By this time, if I am upgrading from version 2 to 
        // version 4, my table would already contain the new column I am trying to add below, 
        // which would result in a SQLException. These situations are sometimes difficult to spot, 
        // as you basically need to test from every different version of database to upgrade from. 
        // Some upgrades might work and some might fail with this method.
        // It is best to follow the other method that is on the master branch of this repo.
        if (oldVersion < 4){
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + BookEntry.TABLE_NAME  + " ADD COLUMN calculated_pages_times_rating INTEGER;");
        }
        //As you can probably imagine, this is a terrible way to do upgrades, Please DONT DO IT!!!!

     }


       @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Updating table from " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);

            //Added new column to book table - book rating 
            if (oldVersion < 2){
                db.execSQL(DROP + BookEntry.TABLE_NAME);
                db.execSQL(BookEntry.SQL_CREATE_BOOK_ENTRY_TABLE);
            }
            //Rename table to book_information - this is where things will start failing.
            if (oldVersion < 3){
                db.execSQL(DROP + BookEntry.TABLE_NAME);
                db.execSQL(BookEntry.SQL_CREATE_BOOK_ENTRY_TABLE);
            }
            // Add new column for a calculated value. By this time, if I am upgrading from version 2 to 
            // version 4, my table would already contain the new column I am trying to add below, 
            // which would result in a SQLException. These situations are sometimes difficult to spot, 
            // as you basically need to test from every different version of database to upgrade from. 
            // Some upgrades might work and some might fail with this method.
            // It is best to follow the other method that is on the master branch of this repo.
            if (oldVersion < 4){
                db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + BookEntry.TABLE_NAME  + " ADD COLUMN calculated_pages_times_rating INTEGER;");
            }
            //As you can probably imagine, this is a terrible way to do upgrades, Please DONT DO IT!!!!


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

when you change your database version in your SQLiteOpenHelper class
    void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, 
                int oldVersion, 
                int newVersion)
will be called for users having old database version.
You should modify database here to include your modification added in new database version.
Existing users data will not be deleted if you remove drop table command from this method

Comment: Thanx @Jagroshan. for explanation.